# Installing kernel 3.10.24 headers on raspbmc

Tags: raspbmc, kernel

I'm trying to build drivers for my wifi dongle (a LogiLink WL0084B), but for that I need to download kernel headers for my current kernel (3.10.24). I'm using raspbmc.

Sadly I cannot find where to download them and

```
apt-get install linux-headers-3.10.24
```

is returning a not found error.

Any insight on this topic, plz?

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to just tick install and update kernel headers in the xbmc/kodi gui, or in a terminal on the raspberry

```
touch /home/pi/.kernelheaders
```

sources:

http://forum.osmc.tv/showthread.php?tid=10263

http://www.raspbmc.com/2013/03/raspbmcs-march-update/